# SQLAlchemy + Marshmallow 'Unknown field.' error in a Many To One relationship although field is present

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

**My issue**

I'm working on a `Flask` app, and I am trying to validate my `marshmallow` schemas in link with some `Sqlalchemy` models. For two objects in a many-to-one relationship, the validation fails because supposedly one of the fields of the parent is unknown, desptie being obviously present.

**MWE**

I have reduced my files to a simple MWE `pytest`, with no reference to `Flask`, which contains :

- an object `Person` with a `string` `name` that acts as a primary key.
- an object `Submission` with a simple `id` primary key and a field `requester_name`

In other words one `person` can make many `submission`, this is a `many-to-one` relationship, that I have set up exactly like in the sqlalchemy doc.

Here is the code:

```
# tests
from pprint import pprint


from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker


from marshmallow import ValidationError
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema

# sqlalchemy

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()


class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "persons"
    name = Column(String(64), primary_key=True)


# MANY-TO-ONE. One Person can make many Submission
class Submission(Base):
    __tablename__ = "submissions"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    requester_name = Column(String(64), ForeignKey("persons.name"))
    requester = relationship("Person")


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# marshmallow
class PersonSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        load_instance = True


class SubmissionSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Submission
        load_instance = True
    requester = fields.Nested(PersonSchema)



def test_person():#SUCCESS
    try:
        PersonSchema().load({"name": "Maria"}, session=session)
        assert True
    except ValidationError as err:
        pprint(err.messages)
        assert False


def test_submission():#FAILURE
    try:
        SubmissionSchema().load({"requester_name": "Maria"}, session=session)
        assert True
    except ValidationError as err:
        pprint(err.messages)
        assert False
```

Here is the raised `ValidationError`:

```
marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'requester_name': ['Unknown field.']}
```

I would expect this simple code to work since obviously the field is *there* and I don't understand why it doesn't.

**What I tried**

Searching for the issue on the internet or stackoverflow led nowhere, since almost all results were about either people forgetting to pass the right options for their `marshmallow` schemas, or version migration problems.

I have also tried usual irrational things such as changing field names (well not that irrational to check for typos), types and so on.

So I produced a simple MWE, hoping to understand the error, but no luck so far.

Thanks for any assistance you could provide.

Answer (score 3):

I know this was asked a while ago but I want to answer in case someone else stumbles across this.

I had the same issue and figured out a solution based on this thread by user peterschutt: https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-sqlalchemy/issues/305

Try adding include_fk = True to class meta as shown below-- I was getting the same error and this fixed it for me and this was one of the first search results when I was troubleshooting.

```
class SubmissionSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Submission
        load_instance = True
        include_fk = True
    requester = fields.Nested(PersonSchema)
```